# Symfony3 embeded Forms validation not working

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have a Filter and FilterCollection object. The FilterCollection holds a collection of Filters, just like the name indicate.
Now I need to validate everything, so I created a FilterType and FilterTypeCollection Forms. In the FilterCollectionType I have:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('filters', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => FilterType::class
        ));
}
```

And in the FilterCollection definition I have the following:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $filters = [];
```

I created a paramConverter so I could convert elements from my request into FilterCollection ones. In the apply method I try to validate everything by using:

```
public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)

    $filterCollection = new FilterCollection();

    $form = $this->formFactory->create(
        FilterTypeCollection::class,
        $filterCollection
    );

    $form->submit($request->query->all());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $request->attributes->set($configuration->getName(), $filterCollection);

        return true;
    } else {
        throw new FormValidationException($form);
    }

}
```

I was expecting that the validation not only validates the FilterCollection but also the Filters. But the validations I have in my Filter definition, are not working, even if I have validations that should fail, it still passes. I think the validator is not passing on the Filter elements.

Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but perhaps you can take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html -- hope it helps

Comment: I tried to get it to work locally and couldn't.

I did find one workaround.. you can add constraints manually to the fields in your FilterForm, ex.:

        $builder->add('age', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => array(new Regex(['pattern' => '/[0-9]+/'])),
        ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Perhaps you made the same mistake as me, forgetting to add `"data_class"` in the `configureOptions` in the formType.

Anyway, here's the code that works (on fresh install of Symfony 3.3)

DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Filter;
use AppBundle\Entity\FilterCollection;
use AppBundle\Form\FilterCollectionType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // add first filter, so we don't have to implement the collection javascript etc to test quickly
        $collection = new FilterCollection();
        $collection->filters[] = new Filter();

        $form = $this->createForm(FilterCollectionType::class, $collection);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                echo "valid input"; // we don't want to see this ;)
            }
        }

        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Filter.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Filter {
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/[0-9]+/")
     */
    public $name;
}
```

FilterCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class FilterCollection {
    /**
     * @var Filter[]
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    public $filters = [];
}
```

FilterType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Filter'
        ]);
    }
}
```

FilterCollectionType

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FilterCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('filters', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => FilterType::class,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\FilterCollection',
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_filter_collection_type';
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't make a ParamConverter like you did, but that seems beside the point of the question. You can change the code to use a ParamConverter easily.